# Any way to get box-shadow only on content-box

Tags: css, clip, box-shadow, border-box

It would be lovely to have the option of where to place a box-shadow. Currently I have a div with some padding. The background color is set to clip on the content-box. That's good. However the box-shadow that I have appear on hover begins at the border-box. Perhaps there is some super secret css I don't know (one can wish, right?)

I know I can add another div after .wrapper, but I'm looking to avoid that. More curious if it is actually possible to position the box-shadow on the content-box.

```css
.page {
  background: #e9e9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #666;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  background-clip:content-box;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/330/175">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h4>Events</h4>
        <p>Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer?</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do already have this wrapper you talk about , the `<a>` around it.
You need to style it too and apply the shadow to it:

```
.wrapper a {
  padding-bottom:1px;/* to deal with collapsing margin if not reset (to <p> here) */
  display:block;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
.wrapper a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```css
.page {
  background: #e9e9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #666;
  background-clip:content-box;
}
.wrapper a {
  padding-bottom:1px;
  display:block;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
.wrapper a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/330/175">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h4>Events</h4>
        <p>Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer?</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

pseudo approach

```css
.page {
  background: #e9e9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #666;
  background-clip:content-box;
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none; /* allow to reach links or inside wrapper content */
  top:0;
  bottom:1em;
  left:0;
  right:1em;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
.wrapper:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/330/175">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h4>Events</h4>
        <p>Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer?</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks GCyrillus, this does answer the question as posed. The final intent of the design is to have a row of 3 or so containers, or cards. Some will have text that is longer than the others. The containers will be flexed to make them all equal height. Using this solution, the <a> links would have to be flexed as well. There could also be an instance where the entire card will not be wrapped in an <a> tag, in that case this wouldn't work. I was really curious if there were such a thing as background-clip:content-box that could be applied to box-shadows.

In any case, thanks, this does work.

Comment: @unfortunately, shadow are drawn inset or outset from edges, but you could use an absolute pseudo element wich will have the only purpose to draw a shadow **<edit** *added a snippet with the pseudo approach in my answer* **/>**

Comment: Very interesting, didn't think of using a pseudo element. I'll mark this as the accepted answer because I think this is a close to a solution that anything will get, and accounts for all other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;` in your wrapper instead of padding.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.page {
  background: #e9e9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #666;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  background-clip:content-box;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/330/175">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h4>Events</h4>
        <p>Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer?</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ricardo. While this does solve the issue as described, in my particular case I needed the padding as this is working with a negative margin on the parent div to even space out all the children with flexbox. I wasn't prepared to make a full copy of the page I am working on, and this was just a partial. But as I said, does answer the question as posed.

Comment: I see, do you have a working demo now? Including the parent div, so that I can try providing a solution that fits this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to apply the `padding-top` to the `.page` class instead of the `.container` class. A code snippet below might explain

```css
.page {
  background: #e9e9e9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #666;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
 <div class="container">
     <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/330/175">
          <div class="content-wrapper">
             <h4>Events</h4>
             <p>Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer? Want to suggest an event or volunteer?</p>
          </div>
        </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works with `background-clip:content-box;`

Use the following instead of `box-shadow` :

```
   filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15));
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15));
```